# how to plot a map using geopandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

there seems to be an issue with my code. My goal is to plot a map that represents an outcome (population) accross the regions of Benin.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl

database_path = "datafinalproject.csv"
database = pd.read_csv(database_path)
#Creating a geodataframe
points = gpd.points_from_xy(database["longitude"], database["latitude"], crs="EPSG:4326")
map = gpd.GeoDataFrame (database, geometry=points)
```

I get this message when I type `map.plot` and I when I type `map.plot(column='population')`, I get an empty map.

Can you help me solve this problem?
`database.head()` gives :
[image]

Comment: forgot the second line : ``` import geopandas as gpd" and the message I first get is geopandas.plotting.GeoplotAccessor object at 0x7ff723d1c640

Comment: all of the points in your example image are the same! are you sure you have multiple distinct points?

Answer (score 1):

`map.plot()` will work in a Jupyter notebook but not in a normal Python environment.

You should import `matplotlib.pyplot` and add `plt.show()` at the end of your code:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

database_path = "datafinalproject.csv"
database = pd.read_csv(database_path)
#Creating a geodataframe
points = gpd.points_from_xy(database["longitude"], database["latitude"], crs="EPSG:4326")
map = gpd.GeoDataFrame (database, geometry=points) 
map.plot()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hello Albert, thanks for your help. Unfortunately, it did not work, I got a map with one blue point in the middle

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Can you paste the output of `database.head()`?

Comment: one blue point on the map is correct, look at the sample data - there is literally just a single point so far ...